# Infinitely many expresions for $\pi$

Tags: pi

It is known that there are many formulas or sequences that give the exact value of $\pi$,but is there any proof that unlimited of them exist?
Conditioned that when u plot it in a graph the function should not be perfectly equal

Comment: What is your definition of "equal" for two formulae?

Comment: You can rewrite the same formule an in infinite amount of ways, so yes.

Comment: Of course without rewriting ,there must be some kind of proof that infinite expressions exist

Comment: For that you have to define what you mean by rewriting. Maybe someone considers $\zeta(2)$ to be just a rewriting of $\pi^2/6$ and similar; then infinitylord's answer doesn't give us infinitely many different expressions.

Comment: by not rewriting I mean not rearranging the terms of an expression

Comment: If I have a formula $\phi$ for $\pi$, then also $\phi+0$ will give you $\pi$, and also $\phi+0+0$. So there are infinitely many. Without an explanation for what formulas you will accept as different there is not much that can be said. *Not rewriting* is not very helpful. Any proof for that $\phi$ will give you $\pi$ is essentially a proof that $\phi$ can be *rewritten* as the formula that initially defined $\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for $\zeta(2k)$ are known, and are of the form
$$\zeta(2k) = \alpha_{2k} \pi^{2k}$$
So
$$(\frac{\zeta(2k)}{\alpha_{2k}})^{\frac1{2k}} = \pi $$

Comment: see Ramanujan-Sato formulae for Pi in a fast convergin series

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many sequences converging to $\pi$. For example, take any sequence $x_n\to\pi$. Then the sequence

$$x_n+\frac cn$$

will converge to $\pi$ too for any $c\in\Bbb R$.